# iOS : Switching between 12/24 hour times from strings

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

Interesting issue thats caught me out.

I receive string times from a server to a device. which I then convert in to a NSDate.
When the device was set to displaying 24hour times, life was good.

Now I am testing it on a device set to 12hour times. everything has stopped working.  Dates are coming back as null

I first had

```
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
 self.startTime = [dateFormat dateFromString:(NSString *)self.startTime];
```

Worked perfectly for devices showing 24hour dates but not 12hour.

I then tried

```
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"hh:mm"];
 self.startTime = [dateFormat dateFromString:(NSString *)self.startTime];
```

This works fine up until 12 noon, then all dates are returned as null

**Update**

I have also tried adding "a" but this still results in returning null

```
 if (startDate == nil)
 {
      NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
      [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
      startDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:(NSString *)self.startTime];
 }
```

**Update 2**

Adding local, adding :ss adding a all still do not work

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSLocale *twelveHourLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
dateFormat.locale = twelveHourLocale;
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
startDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:(NSString *)self.startTime];
```

Comment: From where self.startTime coming?

Comment: Startime is set to @"14:00"

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's close... I think you need:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
[dateFormatter setLocale:locale];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
startDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:(NSString *)self.startTime];
```

Answer (score 7):

You can try this

```
    12 to 24 hour format


    NSDateFormatter* df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
    [df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
    [df setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
    NSDate* newDate = [df dateFromString:LocationTrackingStartTime];
    [df setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
    newDate = [df stringFromDate:newDate];

   24 to 12 hour format

    NSDateFormatter* df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]];
    [df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
    [df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss"];
    NSDate* newDate = [df dateFromString:[df stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]];
    [df setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
    newDate = [df stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

Comment: suppose my date 2016-11-21 21:25:35 and i want it as 10.55 am but in your code i got 2:55 am

Comment: ya sure . in my php database {
            "date_create" = "2016-11-28 20:21:59";
            fromto = To;
            "is_offer" = 0;
            "job_id" = 0;
            message = "check and time 9:51 am system time";
            "message_id" = 86;
            "message_ref" = 83;
            "message_status" = Send;
            "sender_id" = 1;
            status = 1;
            "therapist_id" = 6;
        }
this data and i just use your code for get time for chat and when i convert it and i got 8:21 PM

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya. Thats the correct output. The code converts "date_create" = "2016-11-28 20:21:59"(which has time in hh:mm:ss format) to 8:21 PM(which is in hh:mm a format). btw you can update the time format as per your need.

Comment: now i just solve my problem with some different style .ya your answer show correct but its problem with my php side .

Answer (score 4):

You have to add am/pm:

```
NSLocale *twelveHourLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
dateFormat.locale = twelveHourLocale;
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"hh:mm: a"];
```

Comment: I did try that but still gives me null

Comment: Tried adding the ss and still null .  The string is @"14:00" going in to hh:mm:ss a and null comes out

Comment: @Burf2000 Did you try adding the NSLocale?

Answer (score 2):

Change 24 hours format to 12 hour format,

```
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    //Set 24 hours date format
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"HH:mm";

    //Here @"your24hours date string" is your string date with 24 hours format
    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"your24hours date string"];

    //Set 12 hours date format
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"hh:mm a";
    NSString *strDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];

    NSLog (@"%@", strDate);

   //Output is in 12 hours date format.
```

Comment: For some reason your code is the only one that worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You wanted to convert an `NSDate` forced to `NSString` to an `NSDate` again.
First you have to convert it to and `NSString`, not forcing it!

I also support 12 and 24 hour formats and i have no problem with it.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSDateFormatter* df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];

[df setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]];
[df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];    
[df setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a"];

NSDate* newDate = [df dateFromString:strDate4Convert];    
[df setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"];    
 NSString *newTimeStr = [df stringFromDate:newDate];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   You just need to set the locale to take the am pm format. And everything else as usual.

    NSDateFormatter * df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]; 
    [df setLocale:locale];
    [df setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
    [df setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    NSLog(@"%@", [df stringFromDate:pickUpDate]);
```